# how to multiply all decimals in a data frame by a constant?

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(id = c("10001", "10002", "10003", "10004"), V1 = c(10,11,15,9.3), V2 = c(5,7,21,30.2), V3 = c(10.3, 11, 19, 12))
> data
    id   V1   V2   V3
1 10001 10.0  5.0 10.3
2 10002 11.0  7.0 11.0
3 10003 15.0 21.0 19.0
4 10004  9.3 30.2 12.0
```

How can I multiply all decimals by 100 and make the data look like this:

```
> data
    id    V1   V2     V3
1 10001   10    5   1030
2 10002   11    7     11
3 10003   15   21     19
4 10004  930 3020     12
```

Comment: If you know in advance that **only** your `id` column is non-decimal, and that **all** other entries are "decimal", then `data[,-1]<-data[,-1]*100 ` will suffice.  Can you be more specific about the types of numbers you expect to encounter?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Check the output of what you suggest with what OP posted as the desired result.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde true enough --- which makes me worry not only about myself but those three upvoters :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft look on the bright side, maybe you have a fan club.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sapply` along the numeric columns and use `ifelse` to multiply any elements with a fractional part, then `cbind` the first column of the original data with this:

```
cbind(data[1],sapply(data[-1],function(x) ifelse(x%%1,x*100,x)))
     id  V1   V2   V3
1 10001  10    5 1030
2 10002  11    7   11
3 10003  15   21   19
4 10004 930 3020   12
```

Comment: +1 I only understood how to derive the expected output from the input after seeing your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

```
> index  <- data[, -1] %% 1 != 0
> data[, -1][index] <- data[, -1][index] *100 
> data
     id  V1   V2   V3
1 10001  10    5 1030
2 10002  11    7   11
3 10003  15   21   19
4 10004 930 3020   12
```

Comment: As I commmented contemporaneously w/ your answer :-),  this works only if all `id` values are nondecimal in the OP's definition.

Comment: Mine leaves out the `id` variable, so it doesnt operate over `id`, it only does over `V1,..., V2`.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It seems safe to assume that OP doesn't intend to transform the id column.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde yeah, but you know that old saying about "assume" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
d.m <- data.matrix(data)
decs <- as.integer(d.m) != d.m
data[decs] <- d.m[decs] * 100
#      id  V1   V2   V3
# 1 10001  10    5 1030
# 2 10002  11    7   11
# 3 10003  15   21   19
# 4 10004 930 3020   12
```

Comment: +1 for this vectorized solution! even if data.matrix is dangerous if **id** is a character for example...

Comment: @agstudy thanks. hmmm, apparently regardless of the content of the first column, if it's character, `data.matrix` will convert it to sequential integers. Is this the danger you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo function `%%` to find the entries with decimal parts.

Beware floating-point approximation error.

```
data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {
    if(is.numeric(x)) {
        x[x %% 1 > 0] <- x[x %% 1 > 0] * 100
        return(x)
    } else return(x)
}))
```